# Any way to recover deleted GitHub remote branch (that was deleted locally also)

Tags: git, github, branch, recovery, data-recovery

I deleted everything. Deleted the remote branch via the webUI, and then removed the ENTIRE repository from my local machine and re-cloned it to the same spot.

Is there any way on earth to recover that deleted branch? In looking at the web UI, there's no record of my deleting the branch, or the pull request I attempted to make with it.

Comment: Do you see any of your commits when typing git reflog?

Comment: if you made the pull request then branch can be recovered

Comment: @Daniel no, because I removed the entire repo locally and then re-cloned it. So if I git reflog I only see stuff since the re-clone

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I didn't successfully make the pull request I think. I was trying to make it and it wasn't working, which is why I deleted everything. Like a fool. (thinking I had saved the work elsewhere and would try again)

Comment: I'm afraid there's nothing to do if it's deleted locally, remotely and not present in your `git reflog`

Comment: so you did not make a pull request and deleted the branch that's too bad and i am afraid that @Daniel is absolutely correct

Comment: That's what I figured. Just tough to accept :'(

Comment: You have to accept it and sorry for your loss man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have deleted your branch locally, remotely and it is not present when you type `git reflog` there is no way to use git to recover your branch.

Furthermore, due to the way git stores branches (in a single workarea, compared to SVN that stores each branch in a subdirectory) the probability of successfully recovering the branch using data-recovery tools is close to zero.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help you. I have own guide when data on my mac was deleted files   or I need to reinstall Mac OS. I prefer to use one recovery program – disc drill 3 check here  https://www.cleverfiles.com/boot-mac-from-usb.html. First of all I create   bootable Mac OS X USB drives for data recovery and after that soft scan my device and restore lost data.

Comment: hey Dave, I already tried Disk Drill, no luck since I had overwritten the location by re-cloning the repo. Thanks though1

Comment: Me neither. I payed $89 for disk drill which didn't work, then the company said it's my own fault for purchasing it without predicting whether the recovery would be successful. Buyer Beware.